Where is the key in Lanayru Temple B2?
warning: minor puzzle spoilers in description
I'm in Lanayru Temple trying to make my way through and reached B2 where there's a room with a refrigerator/heater fan powered in the basement (already heated the room), and has a locked door. The room to the right has ice blocks (with nothing in them) and a pair of buttons.



I've pressed both buttons down with the ice blocks but nothing happens. Though upon stepping on the buttons, there's a small flashing animation of the icon on the button.

What am I supposed to do here? How do I get the key?

It's not enough to have them pressed down together, but you have to press the buttons at roughly the same time while that animation is playing. Simple way to do it is to place a block to the right of the right button and push an ice block toward it. Then as the block reaches the button, walk and press the button on the left, or alternatively, stand on the button and jump at the right time.
You'll be rewarded a chest with the room key for your efforts.

